# How to use foreach to create an array and later update a database

Tags: php, arrays

I have a dynamic form that populates a questionnaire rating scale from information saved in my database. Each rating consists of a "selection" and a "definition".  A scale can consists of any number or ratings.  Here is an example of a 5 rating scale:

```
Strongly Agree = I strongly agree with this statement.
Agree = I agree with this statement.
Neither Agree nor Disagree = I neither agree nor disagree with this statement.
Disagree = I disagree with this statement.
Strongly Disagree = I strongly disagree with this statement.
```

Once the form is populated, the user can edit any of the selections or definitions. My form populates just fine, but I cannot figure out how to correctly populate the POST data into an array if the user submits a change or use that array to edit the information in my database.

Here is my PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fields = "";
    $values = "";

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $fields = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
        $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $entry .= "[". $fields . "=" . $values . "]";

        //Here is the start of the query that I'm building
        //$query = mysql_query("UPDATE `pd_selections` SET `pd_selection` = '  ', `pd_definition` = '  ' WHERE `pd_selection_id` = '$pd_selection_id' ") or die(mysql_error());

    }
}
```

If I echo the "entry" variable, this is what I receive:

[selection_for_1=Strongly Agree][definition_for_1=I strongly agree with this statement.][selection_for_2=Agree][definition_for_2=I agree with this statement.]

How do I pull the selection and the definition out of the array for each rating?

How is that used to update the database?

Am I even on the right track...LOL!?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security purpose you should keep a list of keys you would accept to prevent the user from modifying it, this will keep people from adding non valid data to your form as well as keeping out fields you may not want.

Create an array for selection another for definition, and use it to store the key/value while checking for valid fields:

```
$accept = array('selection_for_1', 'definition_for_1',
                'selection_for_2', 'definition_for_2');
$selection = array();
$definition = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    // if not valid go to next field/value
    if(!in_array($key, $accept))
        continue;

    // if start with selection save to $selection array
    // otherwise to definition array
    if (strpos($key, 'selection') !== false)
    {
        $selection[] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
    else
    {
        $definition[] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}

// count one of the array to select the paired fields 
// and insert or update into database
$total = count($definition);
for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++)
{
    // Update query for the paired selection and definition
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE pd_selections 
                             SET pd_selection = '{$selection[$i]}', 
                                 pd_definition = '{$definition[$i]}'
                           WHERE pd_selection_id = '{$pd_selection_id}'")
    or echo("Could not insert or update selection '{$selection[$i]}', definition '{$definition[$i]}', failed with error:", mysql_error());
}
```

[**Live DEMO.**](https://eval.in/42402)

Comment: Awesome...thank you for your help...I've been looking at this page for a couple of days now...LOL!  My database columns are an auto increment selection ID, template ID, pd_selection and pd_definition. What does the query look like to populate the pd_selection and pd_definition columns?

Comment: So far my query looks like this: $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `pd_selections` SET `pd_selection` = '  ', `pd_definition` = '  ' WHERE `pd_selection_id` = '$pd_selection_id' ") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @CameronEastman see update I've changed the code to have 2 arrays 1 for each field which would make it easier to store it in pairs, so you have to make sure your HTML form is always selection 1, definition 1 then selection 2, definition 2 in order. Keep in mind that if you're doing this per user without using something to tell those definitions and selections are from user X you won't be able to update it per user so you might need to add a new field to your table to define which user inserted it.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help Prix!